# Wordpress и Sharepoint

Tags: wordpress, xampp, sharepoint

Можно ли подключить сайт на Wordpress к порталу на Sharepoint? С учётом того, что Wordpress работает на XAMPP, который использует Apache, и Sharepoint использует в работе Apache.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint из коробки использует IIS, а не  Apache.
У SharePoint  своя структура Веб приложения-Коллекций сайтов-Сайтов-Подсайтов

Думаю, можно с помощью [url-rewrite](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337) перехватывать адрес сайта, и если он удовлетворяет условию фильтра вашей регулярной переменной, то перенаправлять/переписывать адрес на сайт Wordpress